# How can I get the cyclomatic complexity by method of a collection of Javascript files?

Tags: javascript, eslint, cyclomatic-complexity

I want to programmatically extract the cyclomatic complexity of all methods in a javascript project.

I know eslint can do this, but the project already has an `_eslintrc.json` defined, and I would like to avoid modifying it.

Is it possible to get eslint to write the cyclomatic complexity of all methods of a javascript project to a file without changing `_eslintrc.json`, perhaps by configuring it from the command line?

Comment: Write a second eslintrc json that does what you want, and pass that config file name as a cli argument